# Addition of Array with different integer

Tags: c++

Is there any way to add the sum of 2 binary numbers with this code ?
The end result I got when I add 12 and 24 is 010FF6F8(36). Which is different each time I add it up.
Everything works fine until the end when I wanted to add both of the binary numbers that I input into the sum of binary.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x1[10], x2[10], n1, n2, i, j, d1[10],d2[10];
    int s1, s2;

    cout << "\nEingabe Dezimalzahl 1 : ";
    cin >> n1;
    s1 = n1;

    for (i = 0; n1 > 0; i++)
    {
        x1[i] = n1 % 2;
        n1 = n1 / 2;
    }

    cout << "Dual : ";
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << x1[i];
        d1[i] = x1[i];
    }

    cout << "\nEingabe Dezimalzahl 2 : ";
    cin >> n2;
    s2 = n2;

    for (j = 0; n2 > 0; j++)
    {
        x2[j] = n2 % 2;
        n2 = n2 / 2;
    }

    cout << "Dual : ";
    for (j = j - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        cout << x2[j];
        d2[j] = x2[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nTest Addition und Zuweisung : \n";
    cout << "-------------------------------\n";

    int sumBin[10], sumDez;
    int k = 0;

    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = j - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            sumBin[k] = d1[i] + d2[j];
        }
    }
    sumDez = s1 + s2;

    cout << "zahl1 + zahl2 : " << sumBin << " (" << sumDez << ") \n";
}
```

Comment: `cout << sumBin` prints the address of `sumBin` variable, not its contents. You'd need to write code to print individual array elements; it won't magically happen by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will paste now your source code with comments, where the errors are. I did this, while reading line by line. Without using a debugger.

I do strongly recommend that you do the same. Read line by line, and check what will happen.

Additionally. Please use a debugger. That will help you tremendously.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

// Do not open the complete namespace
// Do not use this statement
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // You define a bunch of variables, which are not needed here
    // Variables shall be defined, shortly before they are used
    // And only in the scope, where they are elevant
    // All variables shall be initialized. Always
    // C-Style array shall be avoided, Used std::vector or std::array instead
    // Magic numbers, like 10 shall be avoided. USe constexpr

    int x1[10], x2[10], n1, n2, i, j, d1[10], d2[10];
    int s1, s2;

    cout << "\nEingabe Dezimalzahl 1 : ";
    // Always check the result of an input operation. What if the user enters XXX
    cin >> n1;
    s1 = n1;

    // This will work, but it is not the convential way for a for loop
    for (i = 0; n1 > 0; i++)
    {
        x1[i] = n1 % 2;
        n1 = n1 / 2;
    }
    // After this loop, i has a certain value

    cout << "Dual : ";
    // In this loop you decrement i
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << x1[i];
        d1[i] = x1[i];
    }
    // And now, after this loop, i will be -1. Always

    cout << "\nEingabe Dezimalzahl 2 : ";
    cin >> n2;
    s2 = n2;

    // Same as above
    for (j = 0; n2 > 0; j++)
    {
        x2[j] = n2 % 2;
        n2 = n2 / 2;
    }


    cout << "Dual : ";
    // Strange loop. Source of error. But will work here
    for (j = j - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        cout << x2[j];
        d2[j] = x2[j];
    }
    // Now j is -1. Always

    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nTest Addition und Zuweisung : \n";
    cout << "-------------------------------\n";

    // Variable definition without initialization.
    // Again. C-Style array and magic number
    int sumBin[10], sumDez;
    int k = 0;

    // Remember from above?  i is -1. Always.
    // The following loop will never execute, becuase you set i to -2 in the beginning and then want to
    // run the loop until i>=0. i is nver >= 0. The loop will not rund
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = j - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            sumBin[k] = d1[i] + d2[j];
        }
    }
    sumDez = s1 + s2;
    // std::cout cannot emit all avlues of the array. That you must do manually
    cout << "zahl1 + zahl2 : " << sumBin << " (" << sumDez << ") \n";
}
```

Also you addition algorithm is not correct. You need to add bit by bit and include a carry over bit.

```
#include<iostream>

constexpr unsigned int MaxNumberOfBits = 128;

int main() {

    // Inform user aout this program and what to do
    std::cout << "\nSumming 2 number as binaries\n\nPlease enter 2 integer values:\n";

    // Here we will store our 2 decimal numbers
    unsigned int number1{};
    unsigned int number2{};

    // Read the 2 decimal numbers and check, if OK
    if (std::cin >> number1 >> number2) {

        // Ok, we read the 2 numbers. Now, we want to convert them to binary values

        // Number 1. Resulting array to store value.
        unsigned int binArray1[MaxNumberOfBits] = {};

        // Bit index
        unsigned int index1{};

        // Process complete number 1
        while ((number1 > 0) && (index1 < MaxNumberOfBits)) {

            binArray1[index1] = number1 % 2;
            number1 /= 2;
            ++index1;
        }


        // Number 2. Resulting array to store value.
        unsigned int binArray2[MaxNumberOfBits] = {};

        // Bit index
        unsigned int index2{};

        // Process complete number 1
        while ((number2 > 0) && (index2 < MaxNumberOfBits)) {

            binArray2[index2] = number2 % 2;
            number2 /= 2;
            ++index2;
        }

        // Now, calculate the result. Here, we will store result
        unsigned int binResult[MaxNumberOfBits+1] = {};

        // Go over all bits
        // Use carry bit
        unsigned int carryBit{};

        // Get maximunm index to avoid to do unessary work
        const unsigned int maxIndex = ((index1 > index2) ? index1 : index2) + 1;

        // Add all single bits
        for (unsigned int i{}; i < maxIndex; ++i) {

            // Add bit from each number + carry bit
            binResult[i] = binArray1[i] + binArray2[i] + carryBit;

            // Calculate the carray bit
            carryBit = (binResult[i] > 1) ? 1U : 0U;

            // Handle overflow
            binResult[i] %= 2;
        }

        // Output in reverse order
        std::cout << "\nResult: ";
        for (unsigned int i{ maxIndex+1 }; i > 0; --i) {
            std::cout << binResult[i-1];
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Could not read the 2 integers\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (j = j - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        sumBin[k] = d1[i] + d2[j];
    }
}
```

The i and j in this loop are both -1, so they did not enter the loop.

2.

```
cout << "zahl1 + zahl2 : " << sumBin << " (" << sumDez << ") \n";
```

The sumBin you output is the address, not the content. So the value is different every time。